# Whenever i use SCAN command in redis, the number of keys decreases

Tags: node.js, redis

i use the redis library in node.js, and whenever i use the scan command the number of keys decrease drastically, i had 55 millions records after finishing the scan it became 52 millions, what might be the issue ?

```
client.scan(cursor, 'COUNT', count, 'MATCH', match, function (err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            cursor = res[0];
            var records = res[1];
            if (records.length == 0) return done();
            total += records.length;
            callback(null, records, next);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably those 3 million missing keys had passed their time-to-live but hadn't been removed yet.

Running `SCAN` triggers a read of those keys, which triggers [passive expiration](https://redis.io/commands/expire#how-redis-expires-keys):

> A key is passively expired simply when some client tries to access it, and the key is found to be timed out.

I don't see an explicit reference in the documentation to `SCAN` triggering this, but it's described in [this blog post from Twitter](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/infrastructure/2019/improving-key-expiration-in-redis.html):

> Scan would trigger passive key expiration, when the key is read the TTL will be checked and if it is expired throw it away and return nothing.... This idea of scanning all keys worked, memory use dropped when a scan completed.

Comment: Yes Kevin i think so, i had the same thought but i didn't find anything in the documentation to confirm it, but now it makes sense, thank you Kevin have a nice day

Comment: @abgad Also note that SCAN may return duplicates so your current counting approach may yield inaccurate results